# PHPの関数error_logで作成されるファイルのパーミッション

Tags: php

PHPの関数でerror_logを使って作成されるファイルのパーミッションが644になります。
file_put_contentsで作成されるファイルは664になります。
error_logで作成されるファイルのパーミッションを664にしたいです。
環境：AmazonLinux2,PHP7

以下、試しましたが変わらなかったです。
・httpdのumaskを002に変更
・rsyslogのumaskを002
・php実行ユーザのumaskを002
・ファイル実行者のユーザのumaskを002
・profile,bashrc等のumaskを002

error_log関数のコード

```
<?php

//エラーログをon
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');

//エラーログの記録先を指定
ini_set('error_log', 'error.log');

//エラーログに出力したいデータ
$error_log_data = "ほげ";

//エラーログに記録
error_log($error_log_data);
```

file_put_contentsのコード

```
<?php
$file = "log.txt";
$string = "Hello, PHP";
var_dump( file_put_contents($file, $string) );
```

Comment: ファイルの作成後に`chmod`でパーミッションを変更するのも一つの方法かなと思います。(PHPにも`chmod`関数はあるようですし)

Comment: できれば、Linux側の設定で変更したいんですよね。